# React Native not Linking Modules with Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native

I recently had to start over with a backup for my Android Studio files for my React Native project. When I did that however, all of my modules became unlinked.

[File Directory Without Linked Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtPLs.png) (imgur link)

Each module should have a folder here, but it doesn't, and the application doesn't run as a result.

I tried to run `react-native link` to relink it all, but it said every module was already linked. I then tried to unlink and relink a module manually, but that didn't help.

```
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native>react-native link
Scanning 810 folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules (99ms)
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-appsee is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-appsee is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-config is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-config is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-contacts is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-contacts is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-fbsdk is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-fbsdk is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-firebase-analytics is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-firebase-analytics is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-immediate-phone-call is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-immediate-phone-call is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-permissions is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-push-notification is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-segment-io-analytics is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-vector-icons is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-vector-icons is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

I would have expected them to relink after rebuilding the Android files from a backup, but they do not.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files` in Android Studio.